# Unexpected token on older browsers (non ES6)

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm trying to work out why I get an error on some of my code in older browsers:

```
    var the_dates = new Array();
    Array.prototype.map.call(instance.days.children, i => {
        the_dates.push(makeDateInFormatUK(i.dateObj));
    });
```

I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>

I'm using **Babel** to back-work the code for *non-ES6* compatible devices, but for some reason its not doing its magic:

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions

My `.babelrc` looks like:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
    "transform-es2015-template-literals", {
      "loose": true,
      "retainLines": true
    },
    "transform-es2015-arrow-functions"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I run with:

```
babel /home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/lib/resa-booking.js > /home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/lib-non-es6/resa-booking.js
```

There are no errors, but when I look at the outputted file I still get:

```
var the_dates = new Array();
Array.prototype.map.call(instance.days.children, i => {
    the_dates.push(makeDateInFormatUK(i.dateObj));
});
```

**UPDATE:** As a test I created a **test.js** file, with:

```
var a = () => {};

var bla = 1213;
var test = `foo bar ${bla}`;
```

My .bablerc file has:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"]
}
```

Running it I get:

```
babel /home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/lib/test.js

var a = () => {};

var bla = 1213;
var test = "foo bar " + bla;
```

Its almost as if its just ignoring the **.bablrc** file. If I run it with the following:

```
babel --plugins @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions /home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/lib/test.js
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:178:20
    at Array.map (native)
    at Function.normalisePlugins (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:158:20)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For start your `.babelrc` is wrong (*the array for the `template-literals` plugin should close after the options*)

So it should be

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
    "transform-es2015-template-literals", {
      "loose": true,
      "retainLines": true
    }],
    "transform-es2015-arrow-functions"
  ]
}
```

For you second part you say what the `.bablerc` file contains ... and wondering if the `.bablrc` is completely ignored. Both are wrong names (*should be `.babelrc`*) so make sure the file name is correct.

Comment: @Phil added an extra part to my answer to make sure everything is done correctly.

Comment: Ahhh you star - that did it :) I knew it had to be something silly like that (this is the first time I've used Babel)

Comment: @AndrewNewby no worries, i have never used it :)